# Run Js function only once after 2 seconds from c# code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hello i have the next question, ive got the next function =

```
protected void lnk_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
      LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
      string text = btn.CommandName;
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript( this, GetType(), "script", "alert('"+ text + "');", true );


    }
```

I want to run the function after a second or 1.5 secs because this is running before the page renders visually, causing a "visual bug" on which the li tags (for example) dont get the css properties.

Any suggestion would help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript content should run on the event `DOMContentLoaded` like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){alert('text');});
```

If you're sure you want to use the "dirty" way, use `setTimeout`:

```js
setTimeout(function(){alert('text');}, 1500); // 1500 milliseconds
```

Comment: thank you set timeout is doing it just fine!

Answer (score 0):

In async you can wait using Task.Delay

```
private async Task<Response> ExecuteTask(Request request)
{
    var response = await GetResponse();

    switch(response.Status)
    {
        case ResponseStatus.Pending:
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
            response = await ExecuteTask(request);
            break;
    }
    return response;
}
```